# Core Data Child Ordered Set

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities (Order and Cart) in core data with a parent child relationship. The generated parent class has a property to access the child records.

```
@interface Order : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *carts;

@end
```

Say, Cart has a field 'x', is it possible to tell core data framework to keep the `carts` collection above always ordered by x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with an `NSOrderedSet`.  If you have a logical sort for your children then you should not bother with a `NSOrderedSet` at all and just leave them as unordered.  After that change you can use a `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the children into an `NSArray`.

That will yield better performance for you compared to a `NSOrderedSet` and will let you sort by `x`.

Ordered relationships are very expensive and should be avoided unless there is an absolute necessity.